# WebView inside NestedScrollView not scrolling when web content response has an iframe element inside it with height set to 100%

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I have a `Fragment` where I display the `WebView`. The `Activity` containing the Fragment has `CoordinatorLayout` as its parent. I want to collapse the `Toolbar` when the user scrolls the `WebView`.

Activity layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/cordinator_layout"
                                                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/topic_tile_height"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.NewshuntAppBarLayoutBehavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/topic_tile_collapsing_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <include layout="@layout/actionbar_news"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/category_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/topic_slidingtablayout_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@string/newspaper_category_tabs"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/topics_sliding_tab_margin_top"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/news_list_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/categories_pager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The recommended solution is to use WebView inside NestedScrollView.** 
The XML layout for the fragment is as follows.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/category_webitem_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_item_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This works fine when the response to be loaded in the WebView is simple HTML. But if the response contains an iframe element, then the WebView only fills the view port. I am not able to scroll the `WebView`.

Here is the sample response where WebView does not scroll. Here the height is coming as 100%. If I get a fixed height like 1000dp or something, I am able to scroll the WebView. But I won't get a fixed height from the server.

```
"content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<title></title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div><iframe height=\"100%\" src=\"https://sportscafe.in/s3/sc-s3-static-mum.sportscafe.in/kwc/en_fixtures.html\" width=\"100%\"></iframe></div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

**Although there is more content in the WebView, I am not able to scroll it beyond the text March 29**

[image]

Comment: Did u find any solution for this?

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara: unfortunately, we could not find any solution for this.

Comment: I found one, working very well for me. https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java

Comment: It works for me,
 add This line to NestedScrollview in XML File.

     android:fillViewport="true"

then
    set webview height wrap_content.

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: that solution didn't help me @Opriday

Comment: That solution also is not helping for me